# filtering results using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to filter mysql results based on the following form

```
www.dabndash.com/filter.php
```

mysql code for the filter I have been trying is :

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM paintings 
  WHERE (price BETWEEN '$min_price' AND '$max_price') 
  AND (orientation = '$orientation1' OR orientation = '$orientation2' OR orientation = '$orientation3')
  AND (size_diagonal BETWEEN '$size_min' AND '$size_max')
  AND (primary_color = '$primary_color' AND secondary_color = '$secondary_color')
```

I am not sure why the query is not filtering the results. It should filter results even if any one field is entered by the user.

Comment: You should check which values are present and then build your query based on those values.

Comment: A query gives results, but it does not filter them. Please make your question more clear, in it's current form it remains unknown what you ask about IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You should only use parameters the user have selected and build the query from those. It seems  the orientation, size and primary colours filters can be left empty by the user.

If `$orientation1`, for instance, is empty, the query will return zero results (provided all paintings have a non-empty orientation.

Try to run the query with fewer where clauses and verify that you get expected results.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM paintings   WHERE (price BETWEEN '$min_price' AND '$max_price') 
                          AND (orientation = '$orientation1' OR orientation = '$orientation2' OR orientation = '$orientation3')
                          AND (size_diagonal BETWEEN '$size_min' AND '$size_max')
                          AND (primary_color = '$primary_color' AND secondary);
```